# mysql deadlock: a row being locked by a query twice?

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock, mysql-5.6

I have got one and only one occurrence of MySQL deadlock which I have not been able to find a reason for.

I would like to know:

1. Why did this deadlock occur? Something wrong with schema/query?
2. Why is the query waiting for gap lock? (I am explicitly using primary key in where clause)

The first line of source code gets an exclusive lock using following query:

```
SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `active_user`
  WHERE `user_id` =  111111
    AND `_id` IN (
      SELECT
        _id
      FROM
        `active_user`
      WHERE `user_id` =  111111
        AND `identifier` =  'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com'
        AND find_in_set (`type`,  '1,11,18') > 0
    )
  FOR UPDATE
```

Table create statement

```
CREATE TABLE `active_user` (
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `identifier` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `alias_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `column1` text NOT NULL,
  `column2` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `column3` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `column4` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `column5` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uuid` (`user_id`,`identifier`,`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

From output of command `show engine innodb status`

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2016-04-07 21:05:35 2b822e806700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 12298419769, ACTIVE 1 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 2, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 4 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 3 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 3714739237, OS thread handle 0x2b822da0f700, query id 31607921072 10.0.28.66 connection1 Sending data
SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `active_user`
  WHERE `user_id` =  111111
    AND `_id` IN (
      SELECT
        _id
      FROM
        `active_user`
      WHERE `user_id` =  111111
        AND `identifier` =  'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com'
        AND find_in_set (`type`,  '1,2,8') > 0
    )
  FOR UPDATE
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 76 page no 24486 n bits 96 index `PRIMARY` of table `config`.`active_user` trx id 12298419769 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 24 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 13; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 803a789b; asc  :x ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;
 2: len 6; hex 0002dd0afdd5; asc       ;;
 3: len 7; hex 050000014e2e72; asc     N.r;;
 4: len 24; hex 616264616c68616b626e6968657940676d61696c2e636f6d; asc XXXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com;;
 5: len 24; hex 616264616c68616b626e6968657940676d61696c2e636f6d; asc XXXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com;;
 6: len 15; hex 416264616c68616b20426e69686579; asc john;;
 7: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 8: len 30; hex 7b2263726564656e7469616c5f76657273696f6e223a352c226163636573; asc {"version":5,"recces; (total 423 bytes);
 9: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 10: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;
 11: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;
 12: len 30; hex 7b227069635f75726c223a2268747470733a5c2f5c2f6c68332e676f6f67; asc {"url":"https:\/\/aaaaaa.com; (total 113 bytes);

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 12298419817, ACTIVE 1 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 2, locked 1
3 lock struct(s), heap size 360, 2 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 3714739267, OS thread handle 0x2b822e806700, query id 31607921318 10.0.29.120 connection1 Sending data
SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `active_user`
  WHERE `user_id` =  111111
    AND `_id` IN (
      SELECT
        _id
      FROM
        `active_user`
      WHERE `user_id` =  111111
        AND `identifier` =  'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com'
        AND find_in_set (`type`,  '1,2,8') > 0
    )
  FOR UPDATE
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 76 page no 24486 n bits 96 index `PRIMARY` of table `config`.`active_user` trx id 12298419817 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 24 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 13; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 803a789b; asc  :x ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;
 2: len 6; hex 0002dd0afdd5; asc       ;;
 3: len 7; hex 050000014e2e72; asc     N.r;;
 4: len 24; hex 616264616c68616b626e6968657940676d61696c2e636f6d; asc XXXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com;;
 5: len 24; hex 616264616c68616b626e6968657940676d61696c2e636f6d; asc XXXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com;;
 6: len 15; hex 416264616c68616b20426e69686579; asc john;;
 7: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 8: len 30; hex 7b2263726564656e7469616c5f76657273696f6e223a352c226163636573; asc {"version":5,"recces; (total 423 bytes);
 9: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 10: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;
 11: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;
 12: len 30; hex 7b227069635f75726c223a2268747470733a5c2f5c2f6c68332e676f6f67; asc {"url":"https:\/\/aaaaaa.com; (total 113 bytes);

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 76 page no 24486 n bits 96 index `PRIMARY` of table `config`.`active_user` trx id 12298419817 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 18 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 13; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 803a789b; asc  :x ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000002; asc     ;;
 2: len 6; hex 0002dd0afdd5; asc       ;;
 3: len 7; hex 050000014e2bfc; asc     N+ ;;
 4: len 24; hex 616264616c68616b626e6968657940676d61696c2e636f6d; asc XXXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com;;
 5: len 24; hex 616264616c68616b626e6968657940676d61696c2e636f6d; asc XXXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com;;
 6: len 15; hex 416264616c68616b20426e69686579; asc john;;
 7: len 4; hex 80000002; asc     ;;
 8: len 30; hex 7b2263726564656e7469616c5f76657273696f6e223a352c226163636573; asc {"version":5,"recces; (total 597 bytes);
 9: len 4; hex 80000002; asc     ;;
 10: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;
 11: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;
 12: len 30; hex 7b227069635f75726c223a2268747470733a5c2f5c2f6c68332e676f6f67; asc {"url":"https:\/\/aaaaaa.com; (total 113 bytes);

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

Comment: you're missing a quote at the beginning of `XXXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com'`

Comment: @billynoah Thanks for pointing out. I missed it while replacing original data with fake place holders. certainly not the reason for a deadlock :)

Answer (score 0):

The `FOR UPDATE` clause says that the transaction intends to modify some row(s) where `user_id = 11111`, and does not want anyone else to modify them.

If that were the only thing, then one transaction would delay until the other finished.  But apparently both transactions had *other* locks already in place.

What else exists between the `BEGIN` and this `SELECT`?

**Reformulation**

I suspect this will avoid the lock:

```
SELECT  b.*
    FROM  active_user a
    JOIN  active_user b USING(_id, user_id)
    WHERE  a.identifier = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com'
      AND  a.`type` IN (1,2,8)
    FOR UPDATE
```

Plus, these indexes:

```
INDEX(identifier, type, _id, user_id)
INDEX(_id, user_id) -- in either order
```

(Don't add the last index if it is already the `PRIMARY KEY`, or if `_id` is the PK.)

Comment: this SELECT FOR UPDATE is the first statement after BEGIN